# MySQL Query | Select A Query By Matching A Column Of First Table With Two Columns Of Second Table

Tags: sql, mysql

Making and explaining my question in simple word to make it clear for you. Lets suppose we have 2 tables as shown below.

```
first_table
--------------------------------
ID | FullName | Gender | Status
--------------------------------
1.   Mr. Jhon     M      Active
2.   Mr. Cena     M      Active
3.   Mrs. Lye     F      Active
4.   Mr. Shaw     M      Active
5.   Mr. BigB     M      Active 

second_table
-------------------------------------
ID | Sender_ID | Receiver_ID | Status
-------------------------------------
1.       1           2         Send
2.       2           3         Receive
3.       2           4         Accept
4.       4           3         Blocked
5.       5           3         Waiting
```

Now I want to get the list of all users where I am not there from first table that should not be in second table columns either `Sender_ID` or `Receiver_ID` as an example for `ID=4`. For this user, the result should be as follows.

```
result_output
--------------------------------
ID | FullName | Gender | Status
--------------------------------
1.   Mr. Jhon     M      Active
5.   Mr. BigB     M      Active
```

This result is because as the searched User `4` should not be there himself and the other that are in combination in second table should not be there too as you can see the combination of `2=4`, `4=3` means the result should not contain `4,2,3` and rest all.

Answer (score 0):

A subquery to retrieve all the distinct Sender_IDs and Receiver_IDs from the second_table. Then, we select the users from the first_table whose ID is not present in the subquery result.

```
SELECT ft.ID, ft.FullName, ft.Gender, ft.Status
```

FROM first_table ft
WHERE ft.ID NOT IN (
SELECT DISTINCT Sender_ID FROM second_table
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT Receiver_ID FROM second_table
)

Comment: SELECT ft.ID, ft.FullName, ft.Gender, ft.Status
FROM first_table ft
WHERE ft.ID NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Sender_ID FROM second_table
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT Receiver_ID FROM second_table
)